What happens if I plug in cable and set bridge and set IP address for the same network interface?
Usually I see one of three schenarios:

Plug in cable and set IP address for network interface. Any application can send and receive packets over cable on this interface IP address on the host.
Set bridge and set IP addres but not plug in cable for network interface. Any application can send and receive packets over bridge on this interface IP address on the host.
Plug in cable and set bridge but don't set IP address for network interface. LAN behind the cable is now connected to bridge.

But what happens if all three actions are done (cable is plugged in, IP address is set, bridge is set):

Can applications send and receive packets over cable?
Can applications send and receive packets over bridge?
Is LAN behind the cable connected to bridge? I mean are LAN and bridge work as single network?

I understand that this is bad aproach, but I'm curious to know what exactly will go wrong with this setup. I give these actions as an example:
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set dev eth0 down
ip addr flush dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.1.101/24 dev eth0
ip link set dev eth0 up
ip link set eth0 master br0


what have you observed when you do that?
